# how to display lsb_release info in Conky?

Tags: command-line, output, conky

i'd like to display the output of `lsb_release -ds` in my Conky display. ftr, in my current installation that would output `Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia`.

i had thought of assigning the output of that command to a local variable but it seems Conky doesn't do local vars.

maybe assigning the output of that command to a global (system) variable? but that's a kludge and it's not at all clear that Conky can access global vars.

sounds like an `exec...` might do it but the docs stress that that's resource inefficient and since this is a static bit of info (for any given login session) it seems a waste to keep running it over and over.

so, what to do? suggestions most welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should prefer the `execi` version of exec, with an interval, where you can give the number of seconds before repeating:

```
${execi 999999 lsb_release -ds}
```

Comment: thank you! i thought from the conky documentation that this was the way to go but good to have that confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

-You should use the `${exec lsb_release -ds}` command line in your conky script / config and it will display the desired information for you.

Comment: thank you. and there's no need to be concerned about caution given in the manpage? : "warning: this takes a lot more resources than  other  variables".